# What's the official name of "New" page replacement algorithm?

Tags: reference-request, operating-systems, memory-management

I am studying some page replacement algorithms.

I found an interesting algorithm called "New" algorithm.

From page 17 of this slide (https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs346/2015/notes/Lecture_One.pdf)

The algorithm guarantees that each relation has a working set by subdividing the buffer pools.

I want to read the published paper that presents this algorithm

But I failed to find it after spending multiple hours...
(The google cannot find it.. because of its name?)

Does any one know the related paper?